# Prevent multiple form submission

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form for users to submit their reviews on films. When ever a field is missed a error alert will be displayed asking for the users to fill in the required field, but when you hit the submit button multiple  times the required field alert error is displayed as many times at the button is pressed causing a long list of duplicated errors. How do I prevent this from happening? I have tried disabling the button on submit which works and display the errors once but then the button cant be pressed again. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$('#review_a_film').submit(function (e) {

    var error = false;

    // No value for movie_title
    if ($('#movie_title').val() == "") {
        $('.error').append("<li>Please enter a title </li>");
        error = true;
    }

    // No Value for actor
    if ($('#leading_name').val() == "") {
        $('.error').append("<li>Please enter the leading actors name </li>");
        error = true;
    }

    // No value for rating
    if ($('#rating').val() == null) {
        $('.error').append("<li> Please enter a rating</li>");
        error = true;
    }

    //No value for review
    if ($('#review').val() == "") {
        $('.error').append("<li>Please enter a review</li>");
        error = true;
    }

    if (error) { // If error found dont submit.
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}); // End of .submit function: review_a_film.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just clear the `.error` list at the start of your submit function?

```
$('#review_a_film').submit(function (e) {

    var error = false;

    $('.error').empty();

    //...

}
```

Comment: That works perfectly Ed Hinchliffe how does it work though can not  get my head around how the procedure works ?

Comment: Pressing the submit button on your form calls the submit function. Each time it is pressed you are checking for errors in the form and appending a corresponding message to the error list if errors exist. Finally, you also prevent the default submit action if there are errors. Whilst you were clearing the error flag on each click you were not clearing the error list in the HTML that was added with 'append'. This extra line empties the error list HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to stop submit before validation, and then submit if it passes with something like:

```
$('#review_a_film').submit(function (e) {
    Event.stop(e);
    var form = Event.element(e);

    ...

    if (all is dandy) { form.submit() };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have disable the button and enable the button if there is any error.

```
$('#review_a_film').submit(function (e) {
$(this).attr('disabled',true);

var error = false;

// No value for movie_title
if ($('#movie_title').val() == "") {
    $('.error').append("<li>Please enter a title </li>");
    error = true;
}

// No Value for actor
if ($('#leading_name').val() == "") {
    $('.error').append("<li>Please enter the leading actors name </li>");
    error = true;
}

// No value for rating
if ($('#rating').val() == null) {
    $('.error').append("<li> Please enter a rating</li>");
    error = true;
}

//No value for review
if ($('#review').val() == "") {
    $('.error').append("<li>Please enter a review</li>");
    error = true;
}

if (error) { // If error found dont submit.
    e.preventDefault();
$(this).attr('disabled',false);
}
}); // End of .submit function: review_a_film.
```